# Do BCAA's only help with muscle gain or do they help with weight loss?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, cardio

**About me:** 145 pounds, 170cm tall & female.

**Aim:** build muscle and & lose body fat.

**Currently:** training 5 times a week (1 hour cardio, 1 hour weight training).

**Question:** Would [BCAA's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branched-chain_amino_acid) only help with protein synthesis and muscle gain or do they help with weight loss as well?

Answer (score 2):

BCAAs contain 4 Calories per gram, just like proteins, so they don't likely promote weight loss. Also, BCAAs are used as appetite stimulants in patients on hemodialysis and in cancer patients.
Source: [Nutrientsreview.com](http://www.nutrientsreview.com/proteins/amino-acids/branched-chain-bcaa.html)

I've also found no quality studies that would show that BCAAs help in muscle gain.

The only exercise-related effect of BCAAs seem to be reduced muscle soreness after training.
Source: [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20087302)

Answer (score 0):

You can read more than you care to in [examine.com's article on BCAAs](http://examine.com/supplements/Branched+Chain+Amino+Acids/).  There seems to be some aid to endurance if taken when fasting before training, but not much else.  Effects are minor all around, regardless.